# How to update in table with unique key

Tags: mysql, sql

**table**

```
CREATE table REWARD (  
    HID bigint(15) UNSIGNED zerofill,
    ITEM_ID int  UNIQUE ,
    TYPE varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    IS_USED int ,
    DATE_SERV date ,
    FOREIGN key (ITEM_ID) REFERENCES CODE_REWARD (ITEM_ID),
    primary key (HID,ITEM_ID),
    unique (HID,TYPE,IS_USED)
) ;
```

**SQL QUERY**

```
UPDATE REWARD
    SET IS_USED = CASE ITEM_ID
    WHEN 2  THEN NULL
    WHEN 1  THEN 1
    END
WHERE HID = 1 
AND ITEM_ID in(1,2)
```

error

> FAIL:
> UPDATE REWARD SET IS_USED = CASE ITEM_ID WHEN 2 THEN NULL WHEN 1 THEN 1 END WHERE HID = 1 AND ITEM_ID in (1,2)
>
> Message :
>
> Duplicate entry '000000000000001-background-1' for key 'HID

**data**

| HID | ITEM_ID | TYPE | IS_USED | DATE_SERV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | background | NULL | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | background | 1 | 2022-01-01 |

**expect**

| HID | ITEM_ID | TYPE | IS_USED | DATE_SERV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | background | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | background | NULL | 2022-01-01 |

Can I update in 1 query with this constraint

Comment: `iitem_id` !== `ITEM_ID`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in multiple queries. MySQL checks unique constraints after each row is updated. Either of the individual updates in your example will cause a duplicate.

Or you could temporarily remove the constraint.